# Generate random number different from the last item N in the array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following, which works fine. It generates a unique random number for a given empty array and a Max determined by the another array (data) length. I would like to add a check that does:

- when the array length is = MaxN, I want to store the last value of the array inside a variable so that if it is = to a new random generated number I will call "generateRandomNumber(array, maxN)" again.

  ```
  const generateRandomNumber = (array, maxN, lastN) =>  {
      let randomN = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxN) + 0;

      console.log(lastN)

      if(lastN == randomN) {
          // do your thing
      }

      if(array.includes(randomN)) {
          return generateRandomNumber(array, maxN, lastN);
      }

      if(array.push(randomN) == maxN) {
          lastN = array.length - 1
          array.length = 0;
      }

      return randomN

   }

  export default generateRandomNumber
  ```

however I am always getting undefined inside the console.log. I am passing lastN like so:

let lastN;

I would think that that value which is undefined at first would later get updated inside:

```
   if(array.push(randomN) == maxN) {
        lastN = array.length - 1
        array.length = 0;
    }
```

component where generateRandomNumber is used:

```
...
const utilityArray = []
const tempQuestions = []
let lastN

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      collection: gridItemsCollection,

      intro: false,
      instructions: false,
      grid: true,

      questions: this.props.questions,
      selectedQuestion: ""
    }
  }

  getRandomN = (arr, max, lastN) => {
    let s = generateRandomNumber(arr, max, lastN)
    return s
  }

  hideGridItem(e) {
    let //index = this.getRandomN(utilityArray, gridItemsCollection.length),
        collection = this.state.collection,
        newCollection,
        //updatedGridItem = collection[index].hidden = true,
        questions = this.state.questions.questions,
        n = this.getRandomN(tempQuestions, questions.length, lastN);

    console.log(lastN)

    // this.setState({
    //   newCollection: [ ...collection, updatedGridItem ]
    // })


    // if(this.getAnswer(e)) {
      this.generateNewQuestion(questions[n])
    // }
    // else {
    //   console.log('no')
    // }
  }

  generateNewQuestion(selectedQuestion) {
    this.setState({
      selectedQuestion
    })
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const questions = this.state.questions.questions
    let randomNumber = this.getRandomN(tempQuestions, questions.length, lastN)
    this.generateNewQuestion(questions[randomNumber])
  }

  getAnswer = (e) => 
    e.target.getAttribute('data-option') == this.state.selectedQuestion.correct_option

  render() {
    const state = this.state
    const { collection, grid, intro, selectedQuestion } = state
    console.log(tempQuestions)
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="wrapper-inner">
          <View isVisible={state.intro}>
            <p> intro screen </p>
          </View>
          <View isVisible={state.grid}>
            <Grid gridItemsCollection={collection}/>
            <Question question={selectedQuestion.question} />
            <Controls 
              onClick={this.hideGridItem.bind(this)} 
              gridItemsCollection={collection} 
              answers={selectedQuestion}
              answer={selectedQuestion.correct_option}
            />
          </View>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: if you do `let lastN;` and you don't initialize it, then `console.log(lastN);` of course returns `undefined`;

Answer (score 0):

When you use lastN as a parameter, the local variable lastN takes precedence over global lastN and you are actually updating the local variable, not the global. Just change your argument name.

```
const generateRandomNumber = (array, maxN, lastN) =>  {
  let randomN = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxN) + 0;

  console.log(lastN)

  if(lastN == randomN) {
    // do your thing
  }

  if(array.includes(randomN)) {
    return generateRandomNumber(array, maxN, lastN);
  }

  if(array.push(randomN) == maxN) {
    lastN = array.length - 1 //-> Here you update the local copy, the global is not affected. So rename you argument to... say lastNArg
    array.length = 0;
  }

  return randomN

}

export default generateRandomNumber
```

And don't  forget to initialize your global lastN var like: let lastN = 0;

So, here it is modified:

```
const generateRandomNumber = (array, maxN, lastNArg) =>  {
  let randomN = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxN) + 0;

  console.log(lastNArg)

  if(lastNArg == randomN) {
    // do your thing
  }

  if(array.includes(randomN)) {
    return generateRandomNumber(array, maxN, lastNArg);
  }

  if(array.push(randomN) == maxN) {
    lastN = array.length - 1; //make sure lastN is initialized and you have access to it
    array.length = 0;
  }

  return randomN

}

export default generateRandomNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you declare `lastN` but it is never actually declared for the first time. This means the first time you access it, it'll always be undefined.

You have two options to solve this:

Define `lastN` to some suitable default value (I would think something like `-1` may be suitable based on the code presented).

```
let lastN = -1;
```

Just ignore it. From your code, it doesn't look like `lastN` being `undefined` should even be a problem since the only check you do is `lastN == randomN`, which will always be false if `lastN` is `undefined`.

It looks like it should get updated, but possibly not on the first call. It looks like it depends on how many questions you have. Unless you have 1 question, it won't update for a few tries. Also, if you have zero questions, it'll never update (since `array.push()` will be `1` and `maxN` will be `0`).

Comment: At the moment I have 3 questions only, I have initialised it to be "-1", however the moment it reached this condition "array.push(randomN) == maxN" its value is updated to undefined

Comment: That's... odd. I don't see anything in your code that should be causing that. Are you sure you aren't setting `lastN` somewhere else? Is `questions` a normal JavaScript array? You should see what `console.log(array.length)` gives you.